The Semisimplication of a Galois Representation
Suppose $\rho: G \to \operatorname{GL}(V)$ is a finite dimensional representation which is not semisimple. When we semisimplify $\rho$, what do we lose, and what do we keep? We obviously gain semisimplicity, but what information about $\rho$ does the semisimplification remember/not remember?
Here is the context: when you take a canonical $\ell$-adic Galois rep attached to a weight 2 newform, its mod $\ell$ counterpart $\rho$ need not be semisimple any longer, so we semisimplify.
I want to know what information about $\rho$ we have gained/lost post-semisimplification.
As just one example, is it true that, outside a finite set of primes, $\rho$ and its semisimplification have the same unramified primes and the same char poly of Frobenius at those primes?
This is true $\ell$-adically, as shown in Serre's $\ell$-adic representations book, but I am not sure if it is true mod $\ell$, and I also wish to know if there is more we can say.

The semisimplification preserves characteristic polynomials. It doesn't necessarily preserve ramification. For example, let $K/\mathbb Q$ be a $\mathbb Z_p$-extension consider the representation of $\rho\colon\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb Q)\simeq\mathbb Z_p\to\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb Z_p)$ given by $x\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}1&x\0&1\end{pmatrix}$. Then $\rho$ will be ramified wherever $K$ is, but $\rho^{ss}$ is the trivial rep.

A really good source of examples is elliptic curves. If $E, E'$ are elliptic curves over $K$ and $E\to E'$ is a $K$-rational $p$-isogeny, then $E[p]^{ss}$ and $E'[p]^{ss}$ will be isomorphic as $\mathbb F_p$-representations of $G_K$, even though $E[p]$ and $E'[p]$ need not be isomorphic. What's going on here is that $T_p(E)$ and $T_p(E')$ are two different lattices inside the $p$-adic Galois representation $V_p(E) = T_p(E)\otimes \mathbb Q_p\simeq T_p(E')\otimes \mathbb Q_p = V_p(E')$.

Thank you! Where can I find proofs for this kind of information? For example, how do we know the char polys are preserved?

I'm not sure of a good reference, although it's more-or-less built in to the definition. Fix $g\in G$. View $V$ as a $k[x]$-module with $x$ acting via $\rho(g)$. Suppose that $V_0\subset V_1\subset\cdots \subset V_k$ is a Jordan-Holder sequence of $V$. By definition, $V^{ss}$ is just $\bigoplus V_{i+1}/V_i$. But the structure theorem for modules over the PID $k[x]$ encodes the characteristic polynomial of $g$, and you can read off that both $V$ and $V^{ss}$ have the same char poly, essentially by construction.

Can you turn that last part into an answer? What does it mean that the Structure Theorem "encodes" the char poly of $g$, for example, and why does this mean we can read off that $V$ and $V^{ss}$ have the same char poly? My apologies for the request: I have been trying to work out these details for a good deal of time, and I am missing something.

Related
